# Run Ubuntu from removed HDD via USB enclosure?

Tags: usb-drive, external-hdd

My laptop's current hard drive has only Ubuntu 13.10 installed on it.  My goal is to remove it, put it in a SATA to USB enclosure, and run it from there.  I'll be putting a drive with Windows 8 back in the computer.  Before I go mucking about inside it I'd like to know - is this a feasible idea?

---

**EDIT**

TrailRider was on the money.  It works just fine and SecureBoot is not an issue; however, even with no drive put back inside and no  other drives plugged in Ubuntu recognizes its drive as sdb1.

With an SSD connected through USB 3.0, it seems to be running as fast as it did while inside.  I haven't tried any heavy lifting yet, though.

---

**EDIT**

Interestingly, after I put the Windows drive back in the the computer and booted to Windows once, it would no longer boot again from the Ubuntu drive.  Once I put the Ubuntu drive back in the computer it booted just fine again.  I'll have to investigate more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine, the only snag would be if the Secure Boot stopped you, but as it is not preventing you from booting it now I don't think it will as an external drive.

You may get a strange result when running `update-grub` in that it may find the Windows disk and then include it in the boot menu but I don't see that as being an issue other than it *may* not chain load Windows correctly if you try to select it in the menu(it should boot if both HDs were in the computer, not sure if Ubuntu is outside, It *think* it still would but...). It would not affect Windows loading form it's own disk just if you tried to select it in grub.

One thing you would need to be careful of is to make sure that any new grub install would not install into the Windows drive.  This is were is might get tricky, Ubuntu should see it's HD as `sda` and Windows as `sdb`  You would just want to make sure of that before allowing any grub to install from the updates.

You can check that from the terminal:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

the `-l` tell fdisk to only list the partitions so don't forget it. (that is a lower case letter L not the number 1 BTW)

If one disk has a GUID(gpt) partition table it will tell you that fdisk cannot understand GUID partitions, use GNU Parted you can do that by typing:

```
sudo parted -l
```

You could also just use parted first instead of fdisk.

(Ubuntu will show up as an EXT4 filesystem while Windows will be NTFS, they will not likely be labeled Ubuntu and Windows, unless you have label them yourself)

If you see that Ubuntu sees itself on `sda` then any new grub installs will be fine, if you ever find yourself needing to use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to get Ubuntu booting then make sure that it **only** installs grub on the Ubuntu disk(in this case when booting from the LiveUSB/DVD the external drive should show as `sdb` and the internal will be `sda`) just make sure that you have the box unticked that installs grub on all disks.

Note that booting from the LiveUSB also includes when doing an upgrade/new install, you *may* need to click "Something Else" in the Window on how you are going to install Ubuntu and instruct it to install on sdb.  If it gives you the option to "Replace Ubuntu 13.10 with 14.04 or upgrade to 14.04)  then it should be okay but I would still click the something else to make sure that the box at the bottom is showing that grub will be installed on the proper drive, you can then click the back button and let the install take care of it. If not you will have to use the something else window to force the grub install to the correct disk and will have to select the mount points by hand.

---

One last thing, you may have lower performance from a USB drive as the data transfer will be slower, but it will mostly affect you by programs loading slower, after they are loaded, I doubt you will notice any difference, unless you are doing something that is causing a lot of read/writes on the disk. The programs themselves, should be mostly loaded in the memory.